# Docker Symfony Recipe Update fail because not a GIT repository

Tags: git, docker, symfony, composer-php

My project structure is like this:

- root folder

  - .git
  - docker-compose
  - app

    - composer.json

so my git is not located in the app folder but in its parent

My docker app is rooted with the app folder

When I try to update my recipes with `docker exec app composer recipes:update` it fails with error

```
Updating recipe for doctrine/annotations...

There was an error applying the recipe update patch
Command "git rev-parse --show-prefix" failed: "fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var/www)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
". Output: "".

Update the recipe by re-installing the latest version with:
  composer recipes:install doctrine/annotations --force -v
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Same issue on my end. My work around was to run `recipes:update` on the host, which is painful and clearly not the best.

Also, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75375583/composer-recipesupdate-inside-a-docker-php-container-triggers-fatal-not-a-g which has no solution either.